# ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous after applying if/else condition in Pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessing, dataframe

I want to create a new variable for the dataframe `details` called `lower` after iterating through multiple `data frames`.

- `list1` is a list of string values of a column named `variable_name` in the `details`.
- `vars_df` is another data frame with 2 columns, namely `variable_name` and `direction`. Both columns contain with string values. `vars_df.shape = (19,2)`
  Some values of `variable_name` in `vars_df` are present in `list1` as well as `data_set`.
  `data_set.shape = (32,107)`.`df.shape = (96,1)`

The following code, which aims to do the above:

```
    def get_value(df,list1):
        if ((vars_df['variable_name']) in list1) & (vars_df['direction'] =='up'):
            data = data_set[df['variable_name']]
        else:
            data = data_set[df['variable_name']]-20
            if data < 0:
               data = 0
            else:
               data = data
       return data    

details['lower'] = details.apply(get_value,list1=li,result_type='expand',axis=1)
```

produces this error:

`ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')`

I referred the question.[Truth value of a series is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/) Still I can not rectify the error

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming the error comes from the 2nd line)

[This question on StackOverflow has a great answer to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830081/python-pandas-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous)

Essentially, change

```
 if ((vars_df['variable_name']) in list1) & (vars_df['direction'] =='up'):
```

to this

```
if (((vars_df['variable_name']) in list1) & (vars_df['direction'] =='up')).any():
```

or to this, if all of the values should be True

```
if (((vars_df['variable_name']) in list1) & (vars_df['direction'] =='up')).all():
```

Hope this helps :)